# What to do with ATmega's XTAL pins when using the internal oscillator?

Tags: avr, atmega

The XTAL pin on the ATmega16a for example can't be reused as I/Os and I really don't need an external crystal. What do I do? I assume pulling them either high or low is better than leaving them floating and I assume, pulling them low is better than high, but I have no appnote, datasheet or book to support those assumptions. Any pointers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 29 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8154.pdf) indicates:

> When this [internal] Oscillator is selected, start-up times are determined by the SUT Fuses as shown in
>   Table 8-9. **XTAL1 and XTAL2 should be left unconnected (NC).**

Comment: I'll be darned. Thank you very much! I've looked into countless AVR appnotes but somehow missed this in the actual datasheet. D'oh!

Comment: No problem, I recently clocked an ATtiny26 at 20MHz using an external crystal, and remembered reading up on the XTAL pins in its datasheet.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that on a lot of the ATmega/ATtiny chips, if you are using the internal oscillator, the XTAL pins serve as regular I/O.

Answer (score 1):

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AN2519-AVR-Microcontroller-Hardware-Design-Considerations-00002519B.pdf

On page 18 it states that the XTAL Pins are to be grounded to prevent unwanted oscillations during startup.

Hope this Helps :-)